# Does the isomorphic of the fundamental groups imply the existence of a mapping inducing an isomorphism?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-group

A pair of continuous mappings $f \colon X \to Y$ and $g \colon Y \to X$ is called $\pi_1$-equivalence if they induce mutually inverse isomorphisms of fundamental groups. Spaces are called $\pi_1$-equivalent if there is $π_1$-equivalence between them.

Let $X, Y$ be CW-complexes

1. Is it true that if $f \colon X \to Y$ induces an isomorphism of fundamental groups, then $X$ and $Y$ are $π_1$-equivalent?
2. Is it true that if $\pi_1(X)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(Y)$, then $X$ and $Y$ are $\pi_1$-equivalent?

(added later)

3. Is it true that if $\pi_1(X)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(Y)$, then there is of a mapping $f \colon X \to Y$  inducing an isomorphism or there is of a mapping $g \colon Y \to X$  inducing an isomorphism?

Comment: Do you mean $g:Y\to X$?

Comment: The area addressing these questions is commonly known as "obstruction theory". As Achim Krause's answer shows, it is a much more subtle problem than this.

Comment: @PierrePC Yes, I corrected it, thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No and no. For an explicit counterexample to 1. (which is also a counterexample to 2.) take the map $\mathbb{R}P^2\to \mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I need to think a little about your answer. Are there any counterexamples among finite-dimensional complexes?

Comment: You can replace $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ by $\mathbb{R}P^3$.

Comment: Thanks! I have added a 3rd question that matches the title exactly, maybe less trivial.

Comment: It is also a counterexample to (3). There is no mapping from $\mathbb{R}P^3$ to $\mathbb{R}P^2$ inducing an isomorphism on $\pi_1$.

Comment: @HenrikRüping I beg your pardon, of course, I meant there is a mapping in some direction inducing an isomorphism

Comment: That's a weird thing to expect, don't you think? That there's always a map in at least one direction, but you don't know beforehand in which?

Comment: Here's a counterexample to that version as well. Write $(BC_p)^n$ for the n-skeleton of the standard CW structure on $BC_p$. Let $p, q$ be two different primes. Then $(BC_p)^2 \times (BC_q)^4$ and $(BC_p)^4 \times (BC_q)^2$ have the same fundamental group, but there's no map either way that induces an isomorphism on it.

Comment: @AchimKrause Still, I fail to understand why there is no continuous mapping from $\mathbb{R}P^3$ to $\mathbb{R}P^2$ inducing an isomorphism of fundamental groups. Can you tell me which textbook to look at?

Comment: Hatcher, for example. The idea is to obstruct the existence of such a map by looking at the effect on cohomology rings.

Comment: @AchimKrause Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

As a consequence of [Van Kampen's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Kampen_diagram), in the special case where $X,Y$ are finite 2-dimensional CW-complexes then the answer is yes to all 3.